# Detecting CTRL key in OpenLayers select interaction?

Tags: openlayers

I have an OpenLayers select interaction with an add condition event handler.

```
const addCondition = (event: MapBrowserEvent):boolean => {

  return true;
}
```

In this handler I need to determine if the CTRL key was pressed when the user clicked on a map feature. It does not appear the MapBrowserEvent contains the information to determine if the CTRL key was pressed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use ol/events/condition.platformModifierKeyOnly

Comment: I am using platformModifierKeyOnly but the user can still click on the feature or CTRL click. I need to determine whether the CTRL key was pressed when the user clicked.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with ES6, so this will be old school. You can check individual keys/triggers in the condition function the following way:

```
function addCondition(mapBrowserEvent) {
  var isClick = ol.events.condition.click(mapBrowserEvent);
  var isCtrl = ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(mapBrowserEvent);
  if (isClick) {
    if (isCtrl) {
      ...
      }
    else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

You can then return `true` or `false` according to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

```
function onSingleClick(e : MapBrowserEvent<MouseEvent>) {
  if (e.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
}
```